# Codility binary gap solution using indices

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge

I am seeking a review of my [codility](https://www.codility.com/) solution.

Whilst the problem is fairly simple, my approach differs to many solutions already on this site. My submission passes 100% of the automated correctness tests.

I am looking for feedback regarding the design of my solution, and any comments in relation to how this submission might be graded by a human.

**Problem description:**

> A binary gap within a positive integer N is any maximal sequence of
>   consecutive zeros that is surrounded by ones at both ends in the
>   binary representation of N.
>
> For example, number 9 has binary representation 1001 and contains a
>   binary gap of length 2. The number 529 has binary representation
>   1000010001 and contains two binary gaps: one of length 4 and one of
>   length 3. The number 20 has binary representation 10100 and contains
>   one binary gap of length 1. The number 15 has binary representation
>   1111 and has no binary gaps. The number 32 has binary representation
>   100000 and has no binary gaps.
>
> Write a function:
>
> def solution(N)
>
> that, given a positive integer N, returns the length of its longest
>   binary gap. The function should return 0 if N doesn't contain a binary
>   gap.
>
> For example, given N = 1041 the function should return 5, because N
>   has binary representation 10000010001 and so its longest binary gap is
>   of length 5. Given N = 32 the function should return 0, because N has
>   binary representation '100000' and thus no binary gaps.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..2,147,483,647].

**Solution:**

```
def solution(N):

    bit_array = [int(bit) for bit in '{0:08b}'.format(N)]
    indices = [bit for bit, x in enumerate(bit_array) if x == 1]

    if len(indices) < 2: 
        return 0

    lengths = [end - beg for beg, end in zip(indices, indices[1:])]

    return max(lengths) - 1
```

Comment: This question has also been [asked at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48951591).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Converting from string to int in your first comprehension isn't needed as you're comparing to a literal anyway.
2. You can merge the first two comprehensions.
3. you don't need to return early, as you can default `max` to 1.
4. You shouldn't need the `8` in your format, as it shouldn't matter if there's padding or not, as it'll be filtered anyway.
5. From Python 3.6 you can use an f-string.

```
def solution(N):
    indices = [bit for bit, x in enumerate(f'{N:0b}') if x == '1']
    lengths = (end - beg for beg, end in zip(indices, indices[1:]))
    return max(lengths, default=1) - 1
```